# Creating a symbol to repeat the previous n bars in Sibelius

Tags: notation, sibelius, repeats

Specifically, I'm trying to create a symbol that, similar to the 'repeat the previous 4 bars' symbol, will repeat the previous *n* bars (6 in this example). I've tried duplicating the symbol and editing it, but I don't understand how Sibelius knows what to do with a symbol (and therefore I don't know how its behavior can be edited).

[image: This is what the symbol would look like. as you can see, it's cobbled together from similar looking symbols.]

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated, but may I ask why you want such a symbol? This is probably a matter of personal preference, but I tend to find them harder to read, and extending the duration of the repeat is not going to improve the situation.

Comment: It's for a part with a 6-measure phrase (repeated several times) which fits easily on one line. Generally I agree with you, but I think in this particular case, it won't decrease readability.

Comment: I thought you might be able to do it via the Dictionary, which controls how symbols affect playback, but it doesn't seem to be configurable there. It also doesn't seem to be in the Inspector window either. You might get more info on the Avid Support site?

Comment: We have someone on here who is a Sibelius expert, I think. I'm sure they'll see the tag and be able to respond.

Comment: You're just going to confuse and annoy the musicians.  We really don't want to have to try to count a zillion slashes.  Use the normal start-and end- repeat measure markings.

Comment: Further, if you want the phrase of N bars repeated several times, just indicate so with standard numbers/words over the end-repeat symbol.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the end use is more for parts; adding repeat bars will add them to all parts, which isn't what I want since not all parts have that repeat. I should have added, that like the 2 and 4 bar repeat symbols, the numeric value would be indicated automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concoct a symbol.  But if you want playback, I think it will have to be done the old way, the way we used before Sibelius enabled playback of bar repeats. My picture should be self-explanatory.

This sort of query would be better in a specialised forum.
[www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3](http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3)

[image]